# How to remove content from a text file?

Tags: python, file

We have a text file with specific strings in it. **How would we remove the strings from the file and save it as a new file?**

File content before script runs:

```
This has foo in it.
This could also have foo in it. 
There is none in here.
Competently morph 24/365 markets foo rather than inexpensive customer service.
```

File content after script runs:

```
This has in it.
This could also have in it. 
There is none in here.
Competently morph 24/365 markets rather than inexpensive customer service.
```

Here is what we tried, but cannot figure out how to remove just the string and leave the rest of the content.

```
def main():
  // my target string to remove
  mystring = 'foo'
  // open the file
  f = open("myfile.txt", "r")
  // second file to output content to.
  f2 = open("output.txt", "w+")
  // read file line by line
  flines = f.readLines()
  //iterate through lines
  for x in flines:
    // stuck here.
    // how to find mystring in the line
    // after removing mystring from line, append to f2
```

Comment: Read the old file, only write the lines you want to keep to the new file.

Comment: @ScottHunter i thought of that, but we need to keep certain portions of the lines. I added a before and after to help.

Comment: Do lines matter here? It seems like you can just read the entire contents at once and perform a simple string replacement.

Answer (score -1):

How about using [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

def main():
    mystring = 'foo'
    f = open("myfile.txt", "r")
    f2 = open("output.txt", "w+")
    flines = f.readLines()
    result = re.sub(r"\s?{}\s?".format(mystring), " ", flines)
    f2.write(result)
```